# How can Django QuerySet filters modify the fields for comparison? (Like inet6_aton for IP addresses.)

Tags: django, django-models, filtering, django-queryset

Take this MySQL database for example, which stores IP addresses as strings in either IPv4 or IPv6 format.

```
name  | ip
------+---------------------------------------
Tony  | 127.0.0.1
Jones | 2001:db8:3333:4444:5555:6666:7777:8888
```

This is the equivalent SQL I need to run, where VALUE is the variable determined by the website's user and already converted to a numeric value for comparison:

```
select name from customers where name like 'J%' and hex(inet6_aton(ip)) > VALUE;
```

Here is my filter, which would work if the ip field was already the numeric equivalent instead of a string:

```
filter = Q(name__startswith="J")
filter &= Q(ip__gt=VALUE)
```

Alas, the ip values in the database are only stored as strings. (This is not my decision, and I cannot change it.) I need to perform the hex and inet6_aton functions on the fields in the database.

How can I achieve this?

Note: This is a very simplified version of what I am working with. These filters will apply to multiple searches across dozens of tables per search. I fear I may need to rework much of the established code to get this to work.

Comment: Well the reason it is a string is because MySQL has no native type for that. Certain databases have dedicated types and thus certain queries can do more sophisticated filtering/updating: for example match with a bitmask.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem The data type isn't the core issue here. We store IP addresses in numeric form in other MySQL databases, which makes these kinds of comparisons easier to deal with, but the tradeoff is the required conversion when printing them to a page. In the database above, IPs are stored as strings, so any comparisons must involve `hex(inet6_aton(ip))`. That is what I need to figure out.

Comment: It appears there is not solution for this. What we did was store the IP addresses in the database as the inet6 data type instead of string, which allowed us to use either CharField or BinaryField in the model and compare the integers or bytes respectively.